# Select a Google Maps Polygon outside map control and modify properties

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polygons, google-maps-drawing

I'm trying to modify a polygon when an event is triggered outside the map control and seem to be hitting a brick wall.

i have a series of divs to the right of my map and would like to change the strokeweight property on the polygon to a heavier line when the mouseenter event is fired and reset it to the default when the mouse leave is triggered.

i would also like to be able to select the polygon when they click on this div

```
$( ".zonal" ).mouseenter(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < gPolygons.length; i++) {
   if(gPolygons[i].id == $(this).attr('id')) 
     {
       gPolygons[i].setOptions({strokeWeight: 6.0});       
     }
  }
});

$( ".zonal" ).mouseleave(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < gPolygons.length; i++) {
   if(gPolygons[i].id == $(this).attr('id')) 
     {
       gPolygons[i].setOptions({strokeWeight: 2.0}); 
     }
  }
});
```

i have pushed the polygons out to an array and tried using the following but it doesn't work

```
gPolygons[i].setOptions({strokeWeight: 6.0});
```

Here is a visual of what im trying to do, so when they hover over zone 1 the border line of the polygon will get thicker and if the click on the div the relevant polygon will be selected.

Any help appreciated guys

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the following javascript error in the console: `Uncaught TypeError: gPolygons[i].setOptions is not a function`.

The `poly` object you are pushing on to both the gPolygons and the polygons arrays is not a `google.maps.Polygon` object, so it doesn't have a `setOptions` method.

```
function formPolygon(shapePoly){
  var shapeid = shapePoly.get('id');
  var res = (shapePoly.getPath().getArray());
  var coordsArr = iterateCoords(res);
  // this is not a google.maps.Polygon:
  var poly = {id:shapeid,coords:coordsArr, polycolor:shapePoly.get('fillColor')}
  polygons = $.grep(polygons, function(e){ 
    return e.id != shapeid; 
  });
  polygons.push(poly);
  // push the reference to the google.maps.Polygon into the array
  gPolygons.push(shapePoly);
  console.log(polygons);
}
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/7b7271h8/25/)

[image: highlighted Polygon]

**code snippet:**

```js
var zVal = 999999999;
var polygons = [];
var gPolygons = [];
var curID = "";
var mapMain;
$('#tt').click(function() {
  var res = (selectedShape.getPath().getArray());
  alert(res);
});

$('#tt2').click(function() {
  alert(polygons[0].coords[0].lat);
});

$(".zonal").mouseenter(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < gPolygons.length; i++) {
    if (gPolygons[i].id == $(this).attr('id')) {
      gPolygons[i].setOptions({
        strokeWeight: 6.0
      });
    }
  }
});

$(".zonal").mouseleave(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < gPolygons.length; i++) {
    if (gPolygons[i].id == $(this).attr('id')) {
      gPolygons[i].setOptions({
        strokeWeight: 2.0
      });
    }
  }
});

$('.zonal').click(function() {
  var testid = $(this).attr('id');
  $('#mapOverlay').hide();
  $('#hdActive').val(testid);
  curID = testid;
  clearSelection();
});
var drawingManager;
var selectedShape;
var colors = ['#1E90FF', '#32CD32', '#FF8C00', '#4B0082'];
var selectedColor;
var colorButtons = {};

function clearSelection() {
  if (selectedShape) {
    selectedShape.setEditable(false);
    selectedShape = null;
  }

}

function checkIDSet(e, a) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($('#hdActive').val() == "") {
    alert('Please select a zone');
    return false;
  }
}

function setSelection(shape) {
  clearSelection();
  selectedShape = shape;
  shape.setEditable(true);
  selectColor(shape.get('fillColor') || shape.get('strokeColor'));
  $('#zInd').val(shape.get('id'));
  console.log(shape);
}

function deleteSelectedShape() {
  if (selectedShape) {
    $('#' + selectedShape.id).attr("disabled", false);
    deletePolygon(selectedShape);
    selectedShape.setMap(null);
  }
}

function selectColor(color) {
  selectedColor = color;
  for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; ++i) {
    var currColor = colors[i];
    colorButtons[currColor].style.border = currColor == color ? '2px solid #789' : '2px solid #fff';
  }

  // Retrieves the current options from the drawing manager and replaces the
  // stroke or fill color as appropriate.
  var polylineOptions = drawingManager.get('polylineOptions');
  polylineOptions.strokeColor = color;
  drawingManager.set('polylineOptions', polylineOptions);

  var rectangleOptions = drawingManager.get('rectangleOptions');
  rectangleOptions.fillColor = color;
  drawingManager.set('rectangleOptions', rectangleOptions);

  var circleOptions = drawingManager.get('circleOptions');
  circleOptions.fillColor = color;
  drawingManager.set('circleOptions', circleOptions);

  var polygonOptions = drawingManager.get('polygonOptions');
  polygonOptions.fillColor = color;
  polygonOptions.strokeColor = color;
  drawingManager.set('polygonOptions', polygonOptions);
}

function formPolygon(shapePoly) {
  var shapeid = shapePoly.get('id');
  var res = (shapePoly.getPath().getArray());
  var coordsArr = iterateCoords(res);
  var poly = {
    id: shapeid,
    coords: coordsArr,
    polycolor: shapePoly.get('fillColor')
  }
  polygons = $.grep(polygons, function(e) {
    return e.id != shapeid;
  });
  polygons.push(poly);
  gPolygons.push(shapePoly);
  console.log(polygons);
}

function iterateCoords(arr) {
  var coords = [];
  var base = arr.toString();
  base = base.replace(/\(/g, "");
  var baseArr = base.split("),");
  $(baseArr).each(function(key, value) {
    var cObj = value.toString();
    var tcObj = cObj.split(',');
    var c = {
      lat: tcObj[0].toString(),
      lon: tcObj[1].toString()
    }
    coords.push(c);
  });
  console.log(coords);
  return coords;
}

function deletePolygon(shapePoly) {
  var shapeid = shapePoly.get('id');
  var res = (shapePoly.getPath().getArray());
  var poly = {
    id: shapeid,
    coords: res,
    polycolor: shapePoly.get('fillcolor')
  }
  polygons = $.grep(polygons, function(e) {
    return e.id != shapeid;
  });
  console.log(polygons);
}

function setSelectedShapeColor(color) {
  if (selectedShape) {
    if (selectedShape.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE) {
      selectedShape.set('strokeColor', color);
    } else {
      selectedShape.set('fillColor', color);
    }
  }
}

function makeColorButton(color) {
  var button = document.createElement('span');
  button.className = 'color-button';
  button.style.backgroundColor = color;
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(button, 'click', function() {
    selectColor(color);
    setSelectedShapeColor(color);
  });

  return button;
}

function buildColorPalette() {
  var colorPalette = document.getElementById('color-palette');
  for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; ++i) {
    var currColor = colors[i];
    var colorButton = makeColorButton(currColor);
    colorPalette.appendChild(colorButton);
    colorButtons[currColor] = colorButton;
  }
  selectColor(colors[0]);
}

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 15,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.034997, -7.193612),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    zoomControl: true
  });
  mapMain = map;
  var polyOptions = {
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillOpacity: 0.25,
    id: $('#hdActive').val(),
    zIndex: zVal,
    editable: true
  };
  // Creates a drawing manager attached to the map that allows the user to draw
  // markers, lines, and shapes.
  drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
    markerOptions: {
      draggable: false,
      icon: 'http://www.myiconfinder.com/uploads/iconsets/256-256-a5485b563efc4511e0cd8bd04ad0fe9e.png'
    },
    polylineOptions: {
      editable: true
    },
    rectangleOptions: polyOptions,
    circleOptions: polyOptions,
    polygonOptions: polyOptions,
    drawingControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
      drawingModes: [
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON
      ]
    },
    map: map
  });
  var iwfMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: 55.034997,
      lng: -7.193612
    },
    icon: 'http://www.myiconfinder.com/uploads/iconsets/256-256-a5485b563efc4511e0cd8bd04ad0fe9e.png',
    map: map
  });
  iwfMarker.setMap(map);
  google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(e) {
    zVal = zVal - 1000000;
    if (e.type != google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER) {
      // Switch back to non-drawing mode after drawing a shape.
      drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);


      // Add an event listener that selects the newly-drawn shape when the user
      // mouses down on it.
      var newShape = e.overlay;

      //Check to see if the shape has an id if not alert user to pick a zone
      newShape.type = e.type;
      newShape.id = curID;
      //newShape.zIndex=zVal;
      newShape.set('zIndex', zVal);
      $('#' + curID).addClass("set", true);
      google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, 'click', function() {
        if (this.id == "" || this.id == null) {
          alert('no id');
        }
        setSelection(newShape);
      });
      setSelection(newShape);
      formPolygon(newShape);
      clearSelection();
    }
  });

  // Clear the current selection when the drawing mode is changed, or when the
  // map is clicked.
  google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'drawingmode_changed', clearSelection);
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', clearSelection);
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('delete-button'), 'click', deleteSelectedShape);

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('map'), 'click', checkIDSet);

  buildColorPalette();
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
#zonalCont {
   position: relative;
 }
 .zonal {
   width: 30%;
   border: 2px solid blue;
   background-color: #cecece;
   height: 55px;
   border-bottom: 20px;
 }
 .zonal.set {
   width: 30%;
   border: 2px solid blue;
   background-color: red;
   height: 55px;
   border-bottom: 20px;
 }
 #map,
 html,
 body {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   height: 100%;
 }
 #panel {
   width: 200px;
   font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
   font-size: 13px;
   float: right;
   margin: 10px;
 }
 #color-palette {
   clear: both;
 }
 .color-button {
   width: 14px;
   height: 14px;
   font-size: 0;
   margin: 2px;
   float: left;
   cursor: pointer;
 }
 #delete-button {
   margin-top: 5px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=drawing&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<span id="tt">Test</span>
<span id="tt2">Test Sel</span>
<div id="panel">
  <div>
    <div class='zonalCont'>
      <div id="zone1" class="zonal">Zone 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class='zonalCont'>
      <div id="zone2" class="zonal">Zone 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class='zonalCont'>
      <div id="zone3" class="zonal">Zone 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class='zonalCont'>
      <div id="zone4" class="zonal">Zone 4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="color-palette"></div>
  <div>
    <button id="delete-button">Delete Selected Shape</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="zInd" />
  </div>
</div>

<div id="map"></div>
<div id="mapOverlay" style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;width:75%;height:100%;background-color:#fff;opacity:0.5;text-align:center">
  <h2 style="line-height:15em">Select A Zone</h2>
</div>
<input type="hidden" class="hdAct" id="hdActive" value="" />
```